# What is the source of the User.Id in Azure MobileServiceUser

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services

I am using Azure Mobile App Services to create a backend for Xamarin native clients and web clients.

I need a consistent user id for my users that will work on all platforms as I expect them to use more than one platform (at least their phone and a browser).  From what I can tell, there are at least four values (not including my own) that are used to somehow "identify" a user.

On the client side, using `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceUser`, when I look at user.Id, I get `sid:18a8227509fb6******bfc976b646e5`. I have no idea where this comes from.

When I hit the `./auth/me` endpoint after logging in, I find a `user_id` claim which clearly is my login name.  So that has to be coming from the access_token that's traveling around in the HTTP headers, right?

Also from the `./auth/me` endpoint there's a 'nameidentifier' claim which looks like this: `1015672*****60338`.  This one belongs to the IDP as I can see it on my accounts at the IDPs.  Also has to be coming from the access_token, right?

On the server side, I'm using `System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal` and the `ClaimsPrincipal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value`. When I display that in a browser by doing a direct call to the endpoint, I get the same value as above, but if I call the exact same endpoint from a native app, it results in a value that looks like this: `sid:ea7cc6e1cf19*****39085297c50b8b4`.  No idea where that comes from.

The values do appear to be consistent across multiple logins, which is some comfort.  :)

So pretty clearly we're looking at different tokens from different people.  Which value should I use that will work across all the platforms?

I'm inclined to think I need a custom endpoint that returns my own information along with the provider to which it is linked.  I prefer not to make IDP calls directly from my clients and the less information that has to be stored there, the better.

I am terribly confused.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

TIA

Comment: OK, I've done a little more research.  Using the same exact identity from the exact same identity provider (Google) I get completely different nameidentifier results depending on whether I'm using the browser or whether I'm using a native client (in this case Windows App 8.1).

Comment: Still more research.  There is an open issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/issues/82).

There is also a great explanation of user id's [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/wiki/Understanding-User-Ids).

Please note that the some of the code has been deprecated but the substitutes work.  Working well for native client, but not for browser client.